# Life cycle error in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

After building my project in Jenkins, I ran into this error:

```
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
(org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/A/workspace/pom.xml mvn clean    
integration-test -Dlog4j.configuration=file./src/test/
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Invalid task 'mvn': you must specify a valid lifecycle phase, or a goal in the   
format plugin:goal or pluginGroupId:pluginArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
```

This is a little weird, since I was to build the project using maven via the command line. Why is my repository, via Jenkins not able to build the project, while I could on my local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right in your log file

`Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/A/workspace/pom.xml mvn clean`.

You have miss-configured the job, so it's now trying to execute an in-existent `mvn` task. If your project type is "maven", just type `clean compile package etc` in the input box. Otherwise please post a screenshot of your job's config so we can better understand what's going on

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new to jenkins/maven, so I don't quite follow. For my project in jenkins I set the repository URL to my bitbucket repository. I also set the root POM to: 'pom.xml', and Goals and Options to: 'mvn clean integration-test -Dlog4j.configuration=file./src/test/' in the Build step. How exactly should I configure this?

Comment: That's it right there, your "Goals and options" should not include "mvn" which is the Maven executable itself. Maven will be invoked by Jenkins with the goals and parameters you have specified in that input box

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are specifying mvn as a goal to maven. The **Goals and options** line in jenkins project config should not include mvn: `clean integration-test` for example.

Comment: I got this piece of code from a book, which I'm following the instructions for... The only place I deviated was that I used a bitbucket repository url (mercurial) rather than a subversion url for the SCM section. But what do you think I should change it to?

Comment: try changing Goals and options to: clean integration-test -Dlog4j.configuration=file./src/test/

Answer (score 0):

I personally solved such an error doing a mere

```
rm -rf /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/A/workspace
```

which does equivalently reset everything clean when such a 'sandgrain' has gotten inside somehow and corrupted the build.